# What in the C# spec prevents promotion of ulong to float in binary operators?

Tags: c#, .net

This is an obscure question for C# language nerds.

The rules for promotion of numeric values for binary operators are [listed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12473-binary-numeric-promotions) and specifically mention that an operator on a `ulong` and a signed integral type will fail with a binding error.

However, that section is also marked as "This subclause is informative." and my understanding is that those rules are a side effect of processing the built-in operator overloads using the same overload resolution mechanism as used for resolving method calls.

If that's the case, what's stopping a binary operator on say `ulong`+`int` from being promoted to `float`+`float` since there's an implicit cast for both?

eg: calling `fn(float,float)` is possible with `fn(intArg,ulongArg)` - why not the operator?

In other words, what "non-informative" part of the spec covers this rule? Maybe there's something in the list of built-in operators that enforces this rule that I'm not aware of?

---

I think I found a clue in the [description of the built-in operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12102-multiplication-operator) where the integer, floating point and decimal operators are all listed and grouped separately.

This hints that the set of candidate operators is based on whether either operand is floating point or decimal... but I can't see that that explicitly mentioned anywhere.  All the section on Binary Operator Overload Resolution says is that for built-in operators:

> Otherwise, the predefined binary operator «op» implementations, including their lifted forms, become the set of candidate operators for the operation. The predefined implementations of a given operator are specified in the description of the operator.

Comment: There's no implicit conversion from `int` or `ulong` to `float` because such conversions are lossy.

Comment: There *is* an implicit conversion from both `int` and `ulong` to `float`.  Also, I wasn't asking why there's this rule, but how it's enforced in the compiler spec?

Comment: But you have to use an _explicit_ conversation. `float x = (ulong)1;` will not compile. I also think that constitutes enforcement

Comment: `float x = (ulong)1;`  DOES compile but it's a bad test because the compiler can relax the rules for literal assignments. A better test is `ulong x = 1UL; float y = x;` and it too compiles without an explicit conversion.

Comment: Damn I had that completely backwards. You're right that does compile. It's the inverse that fails because it would chop off the mantissa. I wish they were both compile time errors.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is preventing promotion, there is no `operator +(ulong, int)`, so promotion is required, but there are so many paths for promotion:

```
operator +(float, float)
operator +(double, double)
operator +(decimal, decimal)
```

Therefore this is a problem of overload resolution, the relevant rules can be found in [Better function member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12643-better-function-member) and [Better conversion target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12647-better-conversion-target). The conclusion is that no overload is better than another one, finally such addition fails due to method ambiguity.

Comment: But the rules you've linked to for better conversion target says that float is better than double because float is implicitly convertible to double, but not vice versa.  eg: if you have fn(float,float) and fn(double,double) and call fn(ulongVal, intVal), then that binds to fn(float, float).  Why not for operators?

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out.  When you have overloads of just float and double, float is better.   When you have float, double and decimal none are better than all the others.  Is it really the case that the rules about binary ulong+signed promotion are enforced simply because of the presence of the decimal overload?  If so, that's really obscure.

Comment: You're right, it's hard to make a decision between float and decimal.